# Memory usage for a parallel stream from File.lines()

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am reading lines from large files (8GB+) using Files.lines().  If processing sequentially it works great, with a very low memory footprint.  As soon as I add parallel() to the stream it seems to hang onto the data it is processing perpetually, eventually causing an out of memory exception.  I believe this is the result of the Spliterator caching data when trying to split, but I'm not sure.  My only idea left is to write a custom Spliterator with a trySplit method that peels off a small amount of data to split instead of trying to split the file in half or more.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: and if you want to write your own spliterator here is a good discussion and starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341656/why-is-files-list-parallel-stream-performing-so-much-slower-than-using-collect

Comment: Afaik, you may just try a recent beta of Java 9. It should have a much better parallelizable `Files.lines()` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracing through the code my guess is the `Spliterator` used by `Files.lines()` is `Spliterators.IteratorSpliterator`.   whose `trySplit()` method has this comment:

```
        /*
         * Split into arrays of arithmetically increasing batch
         * sizes.  This will only improve parallel performance if
         * per-element Consumer actions are more costly than
         * transferring them into an array.  The use of an
         * arithmetic progression in split sizes provides overhead
         * vs parallelism bounds that do not particularly favor or
         * penalize cases of lightweight vs heavyweight element
         * operations, across combinations of #elements vs #cores,
         * whether or not either are known.  We generate
         * O(sqrt(#elements)) splits, allowing O(sqrt(#cores))
         * potential speedup.
         */
```

The code then looks like it splits into batches of multiples of 1024 records (lines).  So the first split will read  1024 lines then the next one will read 2048 lines etc on and on.  Each split will read larger and larger batch sizes.

If your file is really big, it will eventually hit a max batch size of 33,554,432 which is `1<<25`. Remember that's lines not bytes which will probably cause an out of memory error especially when you start having multiple threads read that many.

That also explains the slow down.  Those lines are read ahead of time before the thread can process those lines.

So I would either not use `parallel()` at all or if you must because the computations you are doing are expensive per line, write your own Spliterator that doesn't split like this.  Probably just always using a batch of 1024 is fine.

Comment: Combined with the comments regarding the custom Spliterator and JDK9 gives me what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035499/612704) by dkatzel. 
 This problem is caused by the `Spliterator.IteratorSplitter` which will batch the elements in your stream.  Where the batch size will start with 1024 elements and grow to 33,554,432 elements.

Another solution for this can be to use the `FixedBatchSpliteratorBase` which is [proposed](https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams#2-2-code-fixedbatchspliteratorbase) in the article on [Faster parallel processing in Java using Streams and a spliterator](https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams).