# Search in large CSV as fast as Guava Splitter

Tags: java, stream, guava

Since Java 8 was released I found out I don't need over 2 MB Google Guava in my projects since I can replace most of it with plain Java. However I really liked nice `Splitter` API which was both quite fast at the same time. And what is most important - did splitting **lazily**. It seems to be replaceable with `Pattern.splitAsStream`. So I prepared quick test - finding a value in the middle of long string (i.e. splitting the whole string does not make sense).

```
package splitstream;


import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SplitStreamPerfTest {

    private static final int TIMES = 1000;
    private static final String FIND = "10000";

    @Test
    public void go() throws Exception {
        final String longString = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,20000).boxed()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ,"));

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1,3).forEach((i) -> {
            measureTime("Test " + i + " with regex", () -> doWithRegex(longString));
            measureTime("Test " + i + " with string tokenizer", () -> doWithStringTokenizer(longString));
            measureTime("Test " + i + " with guava", () -> doWithGuava(longString));
        });

    }

    private void measureTime(String name, Runnable r) {
        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        r.run();
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - s;
        System.out.println("Check " + name +" took " + elapsed + " ms");
    }

    private void doWithStringTokenizer(String longString) {

        String f = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(longString,",",false);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String t = st.nextToken().trim();
                if (FIND.equals(t)) {
                    f = t;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(FIND, f);
    }


    private void doWithRegex(String longString) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
        String f = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
            f = pattern.splitAsStream(longString)
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .filter(FIND::equals)
                    .findFirst().orElse("");
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(FIND, f);
    }


    private void doWithGuava(String longString) {
        final Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(',').trimResults();
        String f = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
            Iterable<String> iterable = splitter.split(longString);
            for (String s : iterable) {
                if (FIND.equals(s)) {
                    f = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(FIND, f);
    }
}
```

The results are (after a warm-up)

```
Check Test 3 with regex took 1359 ms
Check Test 3 with string tokenizer took 750 ms
Check Test 3 with guava took 594 ms
```

How to make the Java implementation as fast as Guava? Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Or maybe you know any tool/library as fast as Guava Splitter that does not involve pulling tons of unused classes just for this one?

Comment: I thought that pattern `\s*,\s*` might be faster than `Splitter.on(',').trimResults()` but it was even slower so I removed it.

Comment: Have you profiled the runs?

Comment: Did you warm-up JVM? You'd better use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for such benchmarks, not one JUnit test. Also both Pattern and Splitter objects can be constants. What's important here is probably the fact that `Splitter#trimResults` uses `CharMatcher` internally which can be more efficient than `String::trim` because the latter allocates new array each time. Finally, regex can be slower than matching chars sequentially.

Comment: What's 2MB?  Especially when you can ProGuard away unused classes.

Comment: After three runs the results became constant so this should be good for warm up. Thanks for the trim hint. It still means you can't ignore Guava after Java 8. Baybe rebuilding a light version might be a solution.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda follow Louis' advice and use [ProGuard](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) to shrink Guava's size to your needs.

Comment: Can I use ProGuard before adding to my project so that ctrl+space don't show me two `Optional` classes, `Function` classes etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that guava is *so much more* than just the `Splitter`, `Predicate` and `Function` - you are probably not using everything it has to offer; we use it hardcore and just hearing that makes me shiver. Anyhow, you tests are broken - in probably numerous ways. I've used `JMH` to test these two method just for the fun of it:

```
    @BenchmarkMode(org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode.AverageTime) 
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) 
    @Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
    @Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
    @State(Scope.Thread) public class GuavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(GuavaTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .jvmArgs("-ea", "-Xms10g", "-Xmx10g")
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Param(value = { "300", "1000" })
    public String tokenToSearchFor;

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class ThreadState {
        String longString = IntStream.range(1, 20000).boxed().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ,"));

        StringTokenizer st = null;

        Pattern pattern = null;

        Splitter splitter = null;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setUp() {
            st = new StringTokenizer(longString, ",", false);
            pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
            splitter = Splitter.on(',').trimResults();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public boolean doWithStringTokenizer(ThreadState ts) {
        while (ts.st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String t = ts.st.nextToken().trim();
            if (t.equals(tokenToSearchFor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public boolean doWithRegex(ThreadState ts) {
        return ts.pattern.splitAsStream(ts.longString)
                .map(String::trim)
                .anyMatch(tokenToSearchFor::equals);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public boolean doWithGuava(ThreadState ts) {
        Iterable<String> iterable = ts.splitter.split(ts.longString);
        for (String s : iterable) {
            if (s.equals(tokenToSearchFor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                        (tokenToSearchFor)  Mode  Cnt       Score        Error  Units
GuavaTest.doWithGuava                           300  avgt    5   19284.192 ±  23536.321  ns/op
GuavaTest.doWithGuava                          1000  avgt    5   67182.531 ±  93242.266  ns/op
GuavaTest.doWithRegex                           300  avgt    5   65780.954 ± 169044.641  ns/op
GuavaTest.doWithRegex                          1000  avgt    5  182530.069 ± 409571.222  ns/op
GuavaTest.doWithStringTokenizer                 300  avgt    5   34111.030 ±  61014.332  ns/op
GuavaTest.doWithStringTokenizer                1000  avgt    5  118963.048 ± 165510.183  ns/op
```

That makes guava the fastest indeed.

If you add `parallel` to the `splitAsStream` then it will become interesting, a must read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341656/why-is-files-list-parallel-stream-performing-so-much-slower-than-using-collect)

Comment: I think that re-using StringTokenizer is not correct. It's stateful so once you find an element in 1st run then in each run it returns current element.

Comment: Actually I see that `StringTokenizer` does the heavy lifting in constructor - finding the delimiters. Actually I'm not sure if this is still a lazy solution. `StreamTokenizer` would be lazy or `Scanner`.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda ah, so each run of the benchmark would need a new instance of `StringTokenizer`; but then this burden would need to be added to each test - those that use `Splitter` and `Pattern`...

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda edited. guava does "win", but no one said that regex matching is faster then plain character matching. We are comparing different things here. btw guava 21 is java-8 compatible, you can use lambda and functions with it.

Comment: I'll give Scanner and StreamTokenizer a try later.

Comment: Scanner is so ridiculously slow that I won't even post results. Like 10 times slower than Guava. Answer - say sorry to Guava, and get used to it.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda there are a few things... first `jmh` is the de-facto tool to measure, but its easy to get something wrong (I've been through their examples like 100 times - still I feel like I know very little).  It's also interesting why you measure this - for personal interest? The regex btw takes `0.06` millisecond - that's pretty darn fast to me...

Comment: I'm measuring it to get the idea why somebody put so much effort in implementing CharMatcher etc. Also in Java 8 world I'm using like 5% of Guava and I'm looking for replacements to tidy my classpath. It turned out that I'm using just Splitter, Preconditions and String utils. The collection and immutable collections have crazy API and I've already refactored them out carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, you could import just the parts you need in guava:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava

Answer (score 0):

Can you give pattern.split(text) and iterating over the result in a normal for loop, a try. It might be faster than stream. 
Though am not sure if it will beat Guava.

I meant this..

```
private void doWithRegexAndSplit(String longString) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
         String f = "";
         String[] arr = pattern.split(longString);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                String t= arr[i].trim();
                if (FIND.equals(t)) {
                f = t;
                break;
                }
            }       
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(FIND, f);
    }
```

Please check the time of completion for this case.

Comment: It's way slower and memory ineffective. See that the challenge is that there are 20,000 numbers in CSV but you want to stop in the middle and don't split further.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing [`Pattern.splitAsStream(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) to [`Splitter.split(CharSequence)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-) on a [`Splitter.on(char)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#on-char-) instead of on a [`Splitter.onPattern(String)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#onPattern-java.lang.String-). Finding matches to a char is computationally much simpler than finding matches to a pattern (regex).

If you use `Splitter.onPattern(",").trimResults()` then you will get results like the following:

```
Check Test 3 with regex took 608 ms
Check Test 3 with string tokenizer took 403 ms
Check Test 3 with guava took 306 ms
Check Test 3 with guava pattern took 689 ms
```

In which case `Pattern.splitAsStrimg(CharSequence)` actually performs better than Guava's implementation (assuming this is a valid benchmark, which is always questionable because we're not using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)).

I am not aware of any JDK `char` delimited splitting solution similar to Guava's `Splitter.on(char).split(CharSequence)`. You could roll your own but Guava's solution appears to be very optimized.

Comment: The point is that Java JDK is missing effective char splitting.