# How to force parallel execution of BufferedStream.lines() with flatMap()?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream, java.util.concurrent

I have some code that looks like this (simplified pseudo-code):

```
[...]
// stream constructed of series of web service calls
Stream<InputStream> slowExternalSources = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
[...]
```

then this

```
public Stream<String> getLines(Stream<InputStream> slowExternalSources) {
  return slowExternalSources.flatMap(is -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)).lines())
     .onClose(() -> is.close());
}
```

and later this

```
Stream<String> lineStream = getLines();
lineStream.parallel().forEach( ... do some fast CPU-intensive stuff here ... }
```

I've been strugging to try to make this code execute with some level of parallelisation.

Inspection in `jps`/`jstack`/`jmc` shows that all the `InputStream` reading is occurring in the main thread, and not paralleling at all.

Possible culprints:

- `BufferedReader.lines()` uses a `Spliterator` with `parallel=false` to construct the stream (source: see Java sources)
- I think I read some articles that said `flatMap` does not interact well with `parallel()`. I am not able to locate that article right now.

How can I fix this code so that it runs in parallel?

I would like to retain the Java8 Streams if possible, to avoid rewriting existing code that expects a Stream.

*NOTE* I added java.util.concurrent to the tags because I suspect it might be part of the answer, even though it's not part of the question.

Comment: 1. `.onClose(is -> is.close())` how does this compile? 2. I believe the `BaseStream.onClose` already is *AutoClosable* 3. `parallel` streams mostly use the FJP unless specified otherwise. 4. Why not collect to a List<String> and do the CPU intensive stuff using a custom `ExecutorService` and multiple threads?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341656/why-is-files-list-parallel-stream-performing-so-much-slower-than-using-collect/34348820#34348820

TL;DR: unbounded streams do not parallelise well with spliterators. Dump the lines into List and then parallel stream it

Comment: @Naman I just copied and pasted pieces  of the actual code to post here, apologies if that close() is in the wrong place

Comment: @diginoise dumping to a List causes OOM, these are huge datasets

Comment: @AlexR I'm afraid, you'll need a more old-fashion solution... how it'll look like depends on whether you need the lines to be processed in order or not.

Comment: The lines don’t need to be in order. I want to use Streams for this so that I can learn Streams really well.

Comment: Besides `.onClose(is -> is.close())` doesn’t work at all (a `Runnable` doesn’t take arguments), it’s obsolete, as the stream returned by the `flatMap` function is already closed automatically. The parallel processing depends of the `Stream<InputStream>`, not the sub-streams. If it doesn’t contain enough elements for parallel processing, don’t use a nested stream.