# Optimize: Calculating MD5 hash of large number of files recursively under a root folder

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, stream, checksum, java-11

My Current way of generating MD5 hashes of all files under a root directory, up to a given depth is shown below.

As of now, it takes about 10 seconds (old intel core i3 cpu) to process appx 300 images, each on average 5-10 MB in size. The `parallel` option in `stream` does not help. With or without it, the time remains more or less same. How can I make this faster ?

```java
Files.walk(Path.of(rootDir), depth)
            .parallel() // doesn't help, time appx same as without parallel
            .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path)) // skip directories
            .map(FileHash::getHash)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `getHash` method used above gives a comma separated `hash,<full file path>` output line for each file being processed in the stream.

```java
public static String getHash(Path path) {
    MessageDigest md5 = null;
    try {
      md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      md5.update(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] digest = md5.digest();
    String hash = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest).toUpperCase();
    return String.format("%s,%s", hash, path.toAbsolutePath());
  }
```

Comment: Is the time consumed IO bound perhaps?

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev I was thinking that since the hashing function is pure, there should be a way to run the processes in parallel ? But yeah, IO bound on the hard disk is a possibility, hence asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream returned by `Files.walk(Path.of(rootDir), depth)` cannot be parallelized effeciently (he has no size so it's difficult to determine slice to parallelize).
In your case for improving performance you need to collect first the result of `Files.walk(...)`.

So your have to do:

```
Files.walk(Path.of(rootDir), depth)
        .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path)) // skip directories
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .parallel() // in my computer divide the time needed by 5 (8 core cpu and SSD disk)
        .map(FileHash::getHash)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Fantastic! got a 3x speed up! can you please give some links to help understand what happened ?

Comment: Sure read accepted answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341656/why-is-files-list-parallel-stream-performing-so-much-slower-than-using-collect